# What would the expected number of swaps in a merge sort be?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, permutations, sorting

If I were given a list of random numbers say x1, x2, .........., xn and these numbers are sorted according to the merge sort algorithm. What would be the number of expected swaps/exchanges which would take place?

Comment: @Newb Wouldn't that only give an answer up to multiplication by a constant? I think OP wants an exact answer in terms of $n$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Let me Google that for you ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis